# Basic radio validation with vee-validate

Tags: radio-button, vee-validate

I'm attempting to incorporate vee-validate validation (version 2) against a basic/simple radio input, such as:

```
<div id="app">
<form id="webform" action='post.php' method='POST' @submit.prevent="doSubmit()">

<input type='radio' name='color' value='blue'> Blue<br>
<input type='radio' name='color' value='pink'> Pink

</form></div> <!-- div id app -->


            <script>
                Vue.use(VeeValidate);
                new Vue({
                    el: "#app",
                    template: '#app',
                    data() {
                        return {
                            p_arr_condition_id: null,
                        };
                    },
                    methods: {
                        doSubmit() {
                            this.$validator.validateAll().then(function(result){
                                if (!result){
                                    //this means a validation failed, so exit without doing anything
                                    return;
                                }
                                //here you would put your form submit stuff
                                window.onbeforeunload = null;
                                document.getElementById('webform').submit();
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
            </script>
```

But I'm unsure where to begin.  I discovered a working example here, however I'm not showing how to actually implement their [example](http://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v2/examples/radio.html).  Their Docs [link](https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate) results in a 404.

Any help/guidance would be super appreciated.

Comment: are you using version 2 or 3?

Comment: version 2, will update my question

Answer (score 0):

The demo iframe has a not-so-obvious slider on the left side that allows you to see the code used in the example. You can also go directly to the [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/y3504yr0l1?initialpath=/%23/radio&module=/src/components/Radio.vue&file=/src/components/Radio.vue:0-73)